# how to identify multiple arrays in a JSON response

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I'm pretty sure response.model.model_to_return is wrong, I try to display on screen the content of the array but my JS structure might be wrong.

JS:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/trafic",
        success: function check(response) {
          //CODE WORKSPACE //
          console.log(response);
          $("#variat").empty();
          for (var model of response.model.memory_return) {
          }

          //CODE  checkview //
          console.log(response);
          $("#display").empty();
          for (var model of response.model.models_to_return) {
          }
        },
        error: function(response){
          //alert('An error occured')
        }
      });
    }, 10000)
  })
</script>
```

Python view:

```
def trafic(request):
    user_msg = request.user
    get_Messages = Message.objects.filter(user=user_msg).values()
    allm = get_Messages.all() 
    get_Memory = Memory.objects.filter(user=user_msg).values()  
    allm2 = get_Memory.all()
    c = {"models_to_return": list(allm)}
    d = {"memory_return": list(allm2)}
    return JsonResponse([c, d], safe = False)
```

JS error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'memory_return')
    at Object.check [as success] ((index):613:44)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:27983)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:28749)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:14203)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:16491)
```

[image: JSON arrays returned by the server]

Comment: you can access array items by their index like `response[0].models_to_return` and `response[1].memory_return` but this structure is weird try the python equivalent  of `{models_to_return: [], memory_return: []}`

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `c = {"models_to_return": list(allm)}` and then `d = {"memory_return": list(allm2)}` and then `return JsonResponse([c, d], safe = False)`, what sort of result are you expecting? How do you think the resulting JSON will be structured? Does that structure make sense? For example, did you instead just want a dictionary *that has two key-value pairs*?